# using jquery plugins that are not part of JQuery UI in laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, npm, timepicker

I am trying to use a jquery plugin (jQuery Timepicker) see the following link for its documentation   [timepicker](https://timepicker.co/) !
I installed it using npm. I like to work offline that is why I am skeptical about using cdns. The problem is that when I initialize it,

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $('.timepicker').timepicker({});
            });


    </script>
```

i get an error:
        jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).timepicker is not a function

i have been working with JQuery UI datepicker which works just fine. I however had to import it in // resources/assets/js/app.js

```
    import $ from 'jquery';
    window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

    import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js';
```

i tried importing timepicker as a widget too

```
     import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/timepicker.js';
```

but I get an error when I run 'npm run dev'

```
    ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/timepicker.js' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\DoMyHomework\resources\js'
     @ ./resources/js/app.js 34:0-44
     @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

```
window.$ = window.jQuery = $;

import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/datepicker.js';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/timepicker.js';

// resources/assets/js/app.js
$('.datepicker').datepicker();
$('input.timepicker').timepicker();
```

```
        ERROR in ./resources/js/app.js
        Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/timepicker.js' in 'C:\xampp\htdocs\DoMyHomework\resources\js'
         @ ./resources/js/app.js 34:0-44
         @ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

How do I work with JQuery plugins such as this. Assistance will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, I was using npm to install the packages. In order to use the dependencies, require the dependency from `resources/js/bootstrap.js`

as follows;

```
window.Dependency = require('dependencyYouWant');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the jQuery plugin is imported after the main jQuery library.

Comment: Hi there. Yes it is. Jquery datepicker is working just fine.  Time picker doesn't.